# Can I iterate over an std::map key range even if the boundary keys don't exist?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, c++14, stdmap

I have a `std::map<int, object>`.

If the map contains:

```
std::pair<1, obj1>
std::pair<3, obj2>
std::pair<4, obj3>
std::pair<6, obj4>
std::pair<8, obj5>
std::pair<9, obj6>
std::pair<14, obj7>
```

**Can I iterate across this map from non-existent keys**, such as `i=5..10` (given that there are not actually any keys 5 and 10 in the map)? I would like to use such values to get output such as:

```
std::pair<6, obj3>
std::pair<8, obj3>
std::pair<9, obj3>
```

Alternatively, is there some other container that can do this? I would not like to use a vector, because in my program there are potentially large gaps between keys that actually contain values, and I don't want to have to iterate across thousands of empty indexes when there are only a few items, for example.

Comment: You want lower_bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()` methods of a `std::map` to locate the iterator for the nearest value of the given key. Consult your C++ book for documentation on how these methods work.

Once you obtain the iterators for the nearest key, you can iterate as usual.

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I needed to know. I should have checked the std::map methods.